How to understand little-o notation as used in Erdős's elementary proof of the PNT?
I am currently attempting to understand Erdős/Selberg's original elementary proof of the Prime Number Theorem (using this publicly available version: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063042/pdf/pnas01544-0034.pdf). I've made my way through most of it but I am getting stuck on something that seems like I should understand fairly easily. Take Lemma 3:
Lemma 3. Let $x\to \infty$ so that $\vartheta(x) = Ax+o(x)$. Then for any prime $p_i$ other than a possible set of primes satisfying $$\sum \frac{\log p}{p}=o(\log x)$$ we have $$\vartheta\left(\frac{x}{p_i}\right) = a\frac{x}{p_i} + o\left(\frac{x}{p_i}\right)$$
where $A = \limsup\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\vartheta(x)}{x} < \infty$ and $a = \liminf\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\vartheta(x)}{x} > 0$.
What confuses me is this: why should dividing by $p_i$ change this equality? Doesn't little-o only care about asymptotic behavior? If we are dividing by $p_i$ can't we just scale to larger $x$?
This kind of statement is made quite a few times and is central to the end of the proof. Some guidance would be great.

If you need to use this result for infinitely many primes $p_i$ then the constant matters. This is shorthand for some kind of uniformity in $p_i$, or at least so I'd assume.

I haven't read the paper, but I'd imagine you'd be able to glean what he meant by reading over the proof of the lemma.
